Getting our oil furnace to temper the defrost cycle of our heat pump
We have a heat pump with an oil furnace for backup heat. The furnace also provides the air handler for the heat pump. My goal is to get the oil furnace to temper the cold air that blows into the house during the heat pump's defrost cycle.
Our oil furnace's control board (FCB) has four basic states: it's off, it's heating, it's cooling, or it's only running the fan. In cooling mode, all the furnace does is run the fan at high speed. In heating mode, it runs the fan, but also fires up the burner. If only the fan is enabled, it runs a low speed.
Our thermostat knows nothing about heat pump defrost cycles. The heat pump does have a terminal (W2) that it energizes whenever it is running a defrost cycle.
Attempt 1: Connect the thermostat's Y to the FCB's Y (cool) and then on to the heat pump's Y. This turns on the heat pump and tells the FCB to run in cooling mode. Connect the heat pump's W2 (defrost enabled) to the FCB's W (heat).
Problem: The FCB will never run heating and cooling simultaneously. The net result is that the FCB remains in cooling mode, and the oil heat never comes on.
Attempt 2: Connect the thermostat's Y to the heat pump's Y, by passing the FCB. Again, connect the heat pump's W2 (defrost enabled) to the FCB's W (heat).
Problem: When the defrost cycle begins, it allows the furnace to enter heating mode, so the defrost cycle is tempered. However, it runs in fan-only mode the rest of the time. Since the air moves slower, the indoor coils get hotter than ideal. When the heat pump runs for a long time, it makes the system to work harder than it should, eventually causing the coolant line to vibrate. Not good.
Proposed solution: Add a normally-closed relay. The control signal would be the W2 (defrost cycle) from the heat pump, which would also still be connected to the FCB's W. The line controlled would be the Y from the thermostat to the FCB. The thermostat's Y would also be directly connected to the heat pump's Y.
When the heat pump operates normally, the FCB is in cooling mode, which runs the fan at high speed. The coils do not overheat. When the heat pump begins a defrost cycle, the FCB receives a request to change from cooling mode to heating mode (the FCB is smart enough that the order in which the Y and W signals are energized/de-energized doesn't matter). Once the defrost cycle ends, the FCB reverts to cooling mode.
I have several questions:

Is there a better solution?
Does my proposed solution sound reasonable?
If so, what relay should be used?

I thought the last question would be easy to answer. I want a relay that opens the normally-closed connection when the coil voltage goes from 0VAC to 24VAC. The NC connection only needs to support 24VAC as well. The current is minimal; I measured 2.4 uA when energized.
I thought I could just take those requirements to a site like mouser and find a suitable relay, but the selection there is overwhelming and the datasheets are hard to understand. I don't think this should be an expensive relay, but sometimes mouser points me at parts that start at over $100, so I don't think I'm finding the right relay. Amazon has something that seems suitable, but there is no datasheet, and I don't want a cheap part that is likely to fail.
What would be useful would be suggesting what kinds of relays might work and translating the requirements I wrote into what I should look for in a datasheet. If you wanted to point to a specific part you think would work, that's fine, too.

funny how when inconvenience hits all that fossil fuel bad save the environment go electric stuff goes out the window.

Stop calling it Heat Pump. It is a compressor and a special valve the reverses the compressor flow and so it becomes a heat pump
